# how to move "wkhtmltopdf" in the right place with terminal commands

Tags: terminal, copy-paste

Hello world so i am way new to mac i am trying to install an older version of `wkhtmltopdf` because the `brew install wkhtmltopdf` installs a rc version that just wont work.

So i found this blog that explains how to install it [here](http://woolydeer.com/2012/installing-wkhtmltopdf-mac-osx.html). but how can i move the file `wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-OS-X.i368` into the /usr/bin dir via the terminal in mac?

Comment: What is an "rc version"? Also don't move or edit files in /usr/bin as Apple upgrades will delete them - should be /usr/local/bin

Comment: "release canidate" so basically not beta just working the kinks

Comment: I woiuld ask on the brew mailing list why they are giving a rc as that seems risky as you have found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same way you would in any unix command line:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv

Comment: Can you summarise (or in this case give the command) not just a link. Also note that this won't work on its own

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 answers ☺:

## Don't do it!

The `wkhtmltopdf` wasn't installed in `/usr/bin`. It shouldn't.
This directory is reserved to standard user Unix commands.

Check carefully where `brew` installed the last `rc` version.

The following command will tell you the truth:

```
type wkhtmltopdf
```

Most probably this installation directory is:

```
/local/bin
/usr/local/bin
/opt/bin
...
```

## How to do it

Once you have located where `brew` installed your not working `rc`,
let's say it's `/local_installdir`.
Once you have built the previous version in a directory,
let's say it's `/local_builddir`
here is how to use `mv` to place this previous version in place:

```
cd /local_builddir
mv wkhtmltopdf /local_installdir
```

If you get a permission denied error message on this operation,
then you will have to prefix this same command with the usual
`sudo`:

```
/usr/bin/sudo mv wkhtmltopdf /local_installdir
```